# Installing a package from Fedora 28 that is missing from Fedora 29 using Rawhide

Tags: fedora, dependencies, dnf

I want to install `texlive-scheme-full` using Fedora 29 Rawhide. During installation one package cannot be found:

```
Error: 
 Problem: package texlive-scheme-full-7:svn44177-15.fc29.noarch requires texlive-collection-texworks, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides texlive-texworks needed by texlive-collection-texworks-7:svn36934-15.fc29.noarch
```

Looking at [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/texlive-collection-texworks) reveals that texlive-texworks is listed as a dependency but the link to it cannot be found.

I assume that those missing dependencies will be built in the (near) future?

I thought of using packages from Fedora 28 in the meantime. Does that make sense? And if yes, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing versions is NEVER openly advised.  Especially in your case with 28 and rawhide this is a most certain recipe for torture and pain.

Also you should be pulling from the official mirrors, be they masters (dlXX.fedoraproject.org) or tiered (mirror.cc.vt.edu/...), where Rawhide does have `texlive-texworks-doc-svn43291-16.fc29.noarch.rpm` which can be found/retrieved via wget|curl/dnf install at:

`https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/t/texlive-texworks-doc-svn43291-16.fc29.noarch.rpm`

Comment: But `texlive-texworks-doc` is only the documentation and not the binary package, which is needed for texlive-collection-texworks